# The ways of saying of situations in which you couldn't achieve your purpose

Tags: grammar

I was reviewing my grammar book and the book mentions the things that we wanted to do but couldn't in different chapters in which it explains tenses separately so I accumulated   these types situations in different tenses under the same question. I would like to ask if they all are grammatically correct and  have almost the same meaning and in which situations would you prefer to use each one if some of them  have distinctly different meaning.

I am going to use the same sentence for different structures.

1.I was going to do washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

2.I was to have done the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

3.I was supposed to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

4.I was supposed to have done the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

5.I was about to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

6.I was meaning to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

7.I meant to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

8.I hoped/ was hoping/ had hoped/ had been hoping to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

9.I planned/ was planning/ had planned/ had been planning to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

10.I intended/ was intending / had intended/ had been intending to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

11.I was thinking of  to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

Comment: This sounds like what the British call "taking the piss". Yes, they are all grammatical. No, each has a distinct shade of meaning. I suggest you use a dictionary as no one is paying me to sort out so many different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to break these down for you:

1.I was going to do [the] washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

This is the most typical way of phrasing the statement.

2.I was to have done the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

This implies that the washing should have happened before something else.

3.I was supposed to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

This indicates that some one or thing required the completion of the washing (it was an order or a prerequisite for another task).

4.I was supposed to have done the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

Similar to 3, but with the additional implication that this task should have been done before some other task or some set time.

5.I was about to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

This indicates the timing of the action. It implies that the action was about to be completed immediately before the discovery of the lacking washing powder. This phrasing would be seen, for example, if a child is explaining their situation to their parent.

6.I was meaning to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

As above, this phrasing is excusing the lack of action with regards to the washing. Also, "was meaning" indicates that this discovery happened in the past, possibly (but not necessarily) not recently.

7.I meant to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

Similar to 6, without implying anything about the time of the discovery.

8.I hoped/ was hoping/ had hoped/ had been hoping to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

This phrasing indicates disappointment with the outcome. Was/had/had been put time modifiers on when this occurred - in the past/past/past before something else.

9.I planned/ was planning/ had planned/ had been planning to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

This phrasing implies that there was intention to do the washing.

10.I intended/ was intending / had intended/ had been intending to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

Very similar to 9.

11.I was thinking of to do the washing but we'd run out of washing powder.

This implies that the washing wasn't really planned, it was simply one possibility that was considered before the obstacle came up.